# Is it possible to sleep without yielding?

Tags: python, gevent, greenlets, grequests

I want to send two asynchronous requests using `grequests.send` with a short but exact delay (say 20 ms) between them. I only want to handle the responses after both requests have been sent.

Putting a `time.sleep` between the two sends doesn't work because `sleep` yields to the response handler for request 1 before request 2 has been sent, so request 2 is sent late.

```
grequests.send(req1, grequests.Pool(1))
time.sleep(delay)
grequests.send(req2, grequests.Pool(1)) # Request is sent late
```

How can I ensure the whole block above is run atomically to ensure as close as possible to the expected wait time between requests, without a busy wait?

Comment: I don't think trying to pause a process for an _exact_ amount of time on a multitasking OS is feasible; your process is at the mercy of the OS's scheduler, which may resume your process later than the requested wait time.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo True. I guess what I mean is 'as exact as possible'. I can tolerate it being wrong by a few ms.

Comment: You can do a "busy wait loop" and watch a clock until the amount of time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way to do this is to not monkey patch time . So do this:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all(time=False)
```

Then when you use `time.sleep` it will NOT yield.

If you use `gevent.sleep`, it will still sleep and yield, should you need that functionality as well.

Be aware that if you use other libraries that use `time.sleep`, they will not yield at that point. But it's rare, so should not be an issue.